# What's difference between ng-model= "name" and ng-model="user.name"

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js can any one help me with this one.
**what the difference between ng-model="name" and ng-model="user.name"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model="name"` refers to `$scope.name` defined in the controller & `ng-model="user.name"` refers to `$scope.user.name` defined in the controller. `$scope.user.name` being a **Compound Form Object** containing multiple fields and mostly used in Form Handling in AngularJS.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ylxJRgQrALIO8VCOew7y?p=preview) is the Plunker

Answer (score 4):

**`ng-model="name"`** refers to your controller variable `$scope.name` in the controller. You can access the updates in the `name` variable in the view via `$scope.name` from the controller.

Whereas **`ng-model="user.name"`** refers to two options first is your controller has an object called `user` in its scope say `$scope.user = {}` and that object has a property `name` i.e, in your controller it will be like `$scope.user={name: 'YourName'}`. The second option is you are using the `controllerAs` syntax of angular and your controller is referred as `user` in your route provider.

You can find more about `ControllerAs` [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

`model="name"` means it's a $scope.name variable itself, and `ng-model="user.name"`it means name variable inside `$scope.user` , which refer to the `$scope.user.name` for to access in **controller**.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to two scenarios

1. variable
2. object

Now lets assume we have two cases

## Case 1

```
var user = "user";
$scope.user=user;

then you can use this in html as follows

<div ng-model="user"></div>
```

## Case 2

```
var user = { "name" : "user" , "email" : "user@ekiras.com"}
$scope.user = user;

then you can use this in html as follows

<div ng-model="user.name"></div>
<div ng-model="user.email"></div>
```

Case 3

```
var user = {"name":"user","role":{"name":"admin"}};
$scope.user = user;

In this case you can refer role as follows

ng-model="user.role.name"
```

So, the main difference is what you are referring to is what `$scope` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model="name"`, field binds with $scope.name, which defined in the controller.
Some times dev'plr may have requirement like to bind field with an object's parameter. `ng-model="user.name"` here 'user' object and name is parameter of user, which defined in the controller as $scope.user.name. 
Mostly used to refer all fields of a form into a single object..... in Anglr....